# Why integer data is returned as string in Postman

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5, postman

I'm using Postman to test my APIs and I get the following response:

```
{
 "Message": "Drinks loaded successfully.",
 "Status": true,
 "InnerData": [
     {
         "id": 1,
         "place_id": "25",
         "drink_type": "1",
         "drink_amount": "2",
         "device_id": "1",
         "created_at": "2018-03-09 14:22:27",
         "updated_at": "2018-03-09 14:22:27"
     }
 ]
}
```

In my DB the **drink_type**, **place_id**, **drink_amount**, **device_id** are all integers but I receive them as strings, what is wrong with them ?

Here is my code used to return this data:

```
public function loadDrinks(Request $request){
    $place_id = $request->place_id;
    $device_id = $request->device_id;

    $drinks = \App\DrinksOrdered::where(['place_id' => $place_id, 'device_id' => $device_id])->get();
    $resp = new \App\Http\Helpers\ServiceResponse;
    $resp->Message = "Drinks loaded successfully.";
    $resp->Status = true;
    $resp->InnerData = $drinks;
    return response()->json($resp, 200);
}
```

Comment: i edited it, thank you

Comment: Did you set them as an integer on your model?

Comment: Can you show me the _\App\DrinksOrdered_ file, please?

Comment: `<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DrinksOrdered extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['place_id','device_id','drink_type','drink_amount'];
}
`

Comment: Check out this https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

Add this to your model to specify the data type:

```
 protected $casts = [
     'drink_type' => 'int',
     'place_id' => 'int'
 ];
```

Answer (score 1):

> The $casts property on your model provides a convenient method of
>   converting attributes to common data types. The $casts property should
>   be an array where the key is the name of the attribute being cast and
>   the value is the type you wish to cast the column to. The supported
>   cast types are: integer, real, float, double, string, boolean, object,
>   array,  collection, date, datetime, and timestamp.

This is from the offical documentation, try something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DrinksOrdered extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'drink_type' => 'int',
        'place_id' => 'int',
    ];
}
```